# JavaScript: browsers support vs pure language support: setTimeout, setInterval

Tags: javascript, node.js, settimeout, v8

JavaScript is just a language and one of its implementations is the `V8` engine. It is used in chrome as well as in node.js.

`DOM` support is not JavaScript language feature, it's a browser feature (there is no `DOM` in pure JS). The same way, `XMLHttpRequest` is not a part of JavaScript. It is a browser addon to the JS language.

**My question** relates to [Philip Roberts' JS conf EU](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ&t=3m6s) talk where he states that, *among others, `setTimeout` is not in V8*. And I think he might be wrong, but I'm not sure and this is my question.

When I open node.js (V8-based) console and type the following:

```
> Promise
[Function: Promise]
> setTimeout
[Function]
> setInterval
[Function]
> XMLHttpRequest
ReferenceError: XMLHttpRequest is not defined
    at repl:1:1
    at REPLServer.defaultEval (repl.js:262:27)
    at bound (domain.js:287:14)
    at REPLServer.runBound [as eval] (domain.js:300:12)
    at REPLServer.<anonymous> (repl.js:431:12)
    at emitOne (events.js:82:20)
    at REPLServer.emit (events.js:169:7)
    at REPLServer.Interface._onLine (readline.js:211:10)
    at REPLServer.Interface._line (readline.js:550:8)
    at REPLServer.Interface._ttyWrite (readline.js:827:14)
```

I see that:

- `Promise` prototype is there, since it's a part of ES6, already available under new versions of node. It's part of the **JS as a language**
- `XMLHttpRequest` is not there, since it's just available in the browsers, it's not part of the language
- **both `setTimeout` and `setInterval` are there**. Philip Roberts says they are not - but I see them available under node.js and **I think they should be, since `setTimeout`/`setInterval` make sense in single-threaded/async environment, no matter if it's a browser or a server**.

I guess he knows what he's saying, but I wanna understand why :)

---

edit:

I see `setTimeout` is a function on `window` object. And basically, `window` is the non-standard stuff.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

He's right in that they're not part of V8.  They *are* however, [part of node.js](https://nodejs.org/api/timers.html) (by way of a module, included by default), and have been designed in a way that they are compatible with the browser spec:

> The timer module exposes a global API for scheduling functions to be called at some future period of time. Because the timer functions are globals, there is no need to call require('timers') to use the API.
>
> The timer functions within Node.js implement a similar API as the timers API provided by Web Browsers but use a different internal implementation that is built around the Node.js Event Loop.